# How to create a GIF loader in HTML website for every page while loading

Tags: html, css, web, gif, loader

I want to add a loader to every page while loading, in my basic html website. I have tried different ways but I failed. So I want a code which actually runs and work properly.

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below code for loading.

First, right after the `<body>` tag add this:

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Loading_2.gif?20170503175831" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Then add the style

```
#loading {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
}
#loading-image {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

If in your project has `jQuery 3.0` then you can use below:

```
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#loading').hide();
  })
```

For older versions of `jQuery` then you can use below:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const preLoader = document.getElementById('preloader-wrapper')
addEventListener('load', () => {
  preLoader.classList.add('hide')
})
```

```css
*,html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main{
  background: gold;
  height: 100vh; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
p{
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
img{
  width:500px ;
}

/* whatever you need */
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}
.preloader{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 50px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid blue;
  border-right: 50px solid green;
  border-left: 50px solid black;
  animation : preloader 1s ease infinite;
  transform: rotate(0);
}
@keyframes preloader{
  to{transform : rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>i wanna to have a simple preloader </p>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1500" >
<!--   whatever you need -->
  <div id="preloader-wrapper" class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="preloader"></div>
  </div>
  
  
</main>
```